# Datadog Profile Permissions

Tags: permissions

Someone knows why the profile of one user is fully working on one Browser, but not in Chrome?
It's something related to tokens?

At the moment we clear the Cache several times, but no Effect.

Thanks!

Comment: Corrupt profile? Try creating a new chrome profile / reinstall chrome. If that doesn't work then create a new user profile at the user level.

Comment: @DavidPostill Thanks for your support. I will try your suggestion.. Kind regards :)